# Problem with zend_db

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

ZF/PHP 
This is my class Votes:

```
class Votes extends Zend_Db_table {

protected $_name = 'votes';

public function vote($object_id, $user_id, $vote){

    $data = array('object_id' => $object_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'value' => $vote);
    $this->insert($data);

    return true;

 }
}
```

The 'votes' has 'id' primary key. 
I get:
 Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
when i call vote. Which means the engine every time try to make an insert with '0' as id's value.
How to force insert to automatically increment 'id' column?

Comment: Pedantic note: You should be extending Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the Vote table id, an auto increment field. This should solve the problem.

Comment: ok, i was convinced that i have id as an auto_increment, now it's ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not add the id - ensure the field type in the database is set to auto-increment
and also set it as primary key using

```
 protected $_primary
```

Answer (score 0):

The id field in the database should be defined to auto increment.

In MySql the syntax is like the following:

```
id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```